# Delete all duplicates in a bunch of .txt files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have ~2000 .txt files. Every file has 500000 or less lines. It`s about 40GB.
All files contain words, each on a new line. Some of the files can contain the same words, that contain other files aka duplicates. So, I need to remove all duplicates and leave every word only 1 time.
I tried to write all lines in 1 file and use awk pattern. Like this:

```bsh
awk '!seen[$0]++' Documents/* > result.txt
```

That not worked. It gave me "Can't allocate memory" error.
Writing all to 1 file is not necessary. Also, it would be great, if I can select not only unique lines but also which length is more than 5 and less than 101 chars. I`m trying to do this on a machine with 8 VCPU and 30GB RAM.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Theophrastus no need to join the files into an aggregate first. The post says the files are already one per line, so a sort -u is all that is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple

```bsh
sort -u Documents/*.txt > result.txt
```

should do it. `sort` already knows how to handle files bigger than memory so you should not get the out of memory error you saw with awk. I must admit I am a little surprised that awk ran out of memory, is it compiled as a 32-bit application?

In general using `sort` is likely to be slower than using the `awk '!seen[$1]++'` approach. You could get the speed back by processing the files in groups.

Comment: Can't say anything about how it was compiled. It is pre-installed in Ubuntu Server 18.04 x64.
Btw, can I specify the length of line with sort? I only need lines, which have more than 5 and less than 101 chars.

Comment: See also: https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq; also sort on most GNU/Linux distributions is provided by the GNU Core Utilities.

Comment: `awk 'length>5 && length < 101' Documents/*.txt | sort -u > results.txt` should handle your additional requirement. In general you should edit this into the question.

Comment: @LucasRamage I am not sure why you are pointing out the `uniq` command. Since the OP says there are multiple files and wants the duplicates removed across the files, the ability to remove adjacent duplicates is of no use for this problem. Using `sort Documents/*.txt | uniq > result.txt` would work but would be much less efficient than `sort -u Documents/*.txt > result.txt` assuming a reasonable number of duplicates. With the `-u` flag sort can discard duplicates before sorting. For 2 identical files of size n, this changes a `2*n*ln(2*n)` problem into an `n*ln(n)`, or over 50% faster.

Comment: @icarus but awk is running out of memory. How can I use it to specify the length of a line? Will it work normally for length?

Comment: @Bukashka awk runs out of memory when you're storing lines in arrays. For simple filtering by length, it's not storing anything, so it won't run out of memory.

Comment: That worked, thank you!